# Build HTML in webpack in dev mode with html-webpack-plugin

Tags: node.js, webpack, ejs, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to build separate HTML files using an `index.ejs` using [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin).

My `index.ejs` has the following block of code.

```
<% if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js"></script>

<% } %>
```

I only want to load these scripts in production.

In my webpack file I'm loading `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to specify the location of the ejs template.

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.ejs'
  }),

...
```

When I run webpack in production mode, with `--env.prod`, it properly builds the file into my `public` directory. But when I run with `--env.dev`, this plugin does not run.

*How can I run `HtmlWebpackPlugin` in development mode to build an HTML file specific to my dev environment?*

Comment: im playing with webpack but have the opposite problem. when I run `NODE_ENV=production webpack` it doesn't create index.html...
Sorry if this aint much help..

Comment: This sounds like a an issue with your webpack configuration. If you post a question I can try and help.

Comment: Does the HTML file not generated at all ? If so can you provide the complete webpack configuration ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `ejs-render-loader` package.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question.